# Storing Kotlin Generics in a single database table

Tags: kotlin, generics, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement a way of using a single database table to hold a number of application settings of varying object types.

I figured I would use generics in order to do this, however, I don't think I'm doing it correctly. This is what my entity looks like so far:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_application_settings")
data class ApplicationSetting<T>(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "application_setting_id")
    val id: Long? = null,

    @Column(name = "application_setting_name")
    var name: String = "",

    @Column(name = "application_setting_value")
    var value: T? = null,
)
```

My Repository:

```
@Repository
interface ApplicationSettingsRepository : JpaRepository<ApplicationSetting<*>, Long> {
    fun findApplicationSettingByName(name: String): ApplicationSetting<*>
}
```

My Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
class ApplicationSettingsServiceImpl(
    private val applicationSettingsRepository: ApplicationSettingsRepository,
) : ApplicationSettingsService {
    override fun saveBooleanApplicationSetting(applicationSetting: ApplicationSetting<Boolean>): ApplicationSetting<Boolean> {
        return applicationSettingsRepository.save(applicationSetting)
    }

    override fun saveIntegerApplicationSetting(applicationSetting: ApplicationSetting<Int>): ApplicationSetting<Int> {
        return applicationSettingsRepository.save(applicationSetting)
    }

    override fun getAllApplicationSettings(): MutableList<ApplicationSetting<*>> {
        return applicationSettingsRepository.findAll()
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error when I then try to run the application:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property com.jre.hireout.database.entities.application.ApplicationSetting.value has an unbound type and no explicit target entity. Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type
```

I get that I'm having an annotation issue, however I'm unsure how to fix it along with getting this to work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for entities with generics in JPA.

The closest you can get is probably to have an entity that keeps the value as String which I guess is what you use in the database as well.

And then have a couple of methods to returning the value using different types, e.g. `valueAsInt`.

You will need to do the conversion yourself.

An alternative would be to have an inheritance hierarchy.
But by default that would map the `value` to different columns.
I'm not sure if you could map it to the same column without anything blowing up.